# Index out of range in room sorting program

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am designing a program that sorts students into rooms based on their preferences. I am having some issues with my last section of code (the part labelled #appends each group happiness to a list - goes through each subgroup in larger group first). The error : list index out of range keeps appearing and I know that I must have made some mistake in the for loop, but can't figure out exactly what it is. If someone could give me a hand with fixing this error I would really appreciate it, as I am fairly new to coding and errors slip by me pretty easily. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide `Names.txt`?

Comment: Just added it! Sorry, I completely forgot to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You forgot to assign the `keep` array after calculating it. Change

   `check_validity(sec_comb, names)`

   to

   `keep = check_validity(sec_comb, names)`
2. The score is the 3rd element which is the element at `[2]`, thus change

   `organised_scored_list[e][3]`

   to

   `organised_scored_list[e][2]`
3. I didn't take a close look at your code but I would change the bounds:

   ```
   for y in range (0,len(sec_comb)):
       for z in range (0,len(sec_comb[y])):
          for x in range(0,4):
   ```

   ```
   for y in range(len(keep)):
       for z in range(len(keep[y])):
           for x in range(5):
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped me solve the problem! (and also pointed out some pretty stupid mistakes)